# Bug about the Enthusiast Badge?

Tags: bug, badges

Yesterday I've been awarded the Enthusiast badge because I visited Physics Stack Exchange 30 days in a row (31 days now). However when I click on the "Recent achievements" icon, I can see that the next badge is the "Enthusiast Badge" and that it's completed at 30/30. Is this intended?

Screenshot attached: [image: bug?]

Comment: Just a hunch, but it might not check for completed badges every single time you show up on the site. It may be on a timer -- like at the start of the next day, see if anything was awarded on the previous day. That would explain why you got your 30 day badge on the 31st day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next badge info is indeed buggy. My display tells me my next badge is the [black-holes] badge but I earned that four days ago. I would guess that tpg2114 is correct and the data is only updated intermittently.

I note there are similar questions on the main Meta, for example: [User profile Badge progress bar shows a completed bar, not the next one to get](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261008/user-profile-badge-progress-bar-shows-a-completed-bar-not-the-next-one-to-get). The question hasn't been answered, but the comments suggest that it's because cached data is being used.

There are quite a few questions on the main meta related to the badge progress display. This is a new feature and it appears to be still a work in progress.

Comment: There seems to be no reason for the downvote; do explain please, if you downvote any question or answer. I am undoing the -1:)

Comment: @user36790: downvotes on the meta don't (necessarily) indicate criticism. They just indicate that the downvoter disagrees with the answer or question. Having said that, I find myself puzzled as to what the downvoter disagreed with. I think everything I have said is obviously true. Maybe they just object to the term *buggy* because they don't consider the behaviour to be a bug.

Comment: The whole Next Badge thing wasn't there yesterday, was it? Who knows, maybe we'll get the new profile page / CSS update in an actual six to eight weeks now.

Comment: Yes, the *Next badge* display is gone again. The SE developers move in mysterious ways.